# Proper use of i18n in react native and impact on performance

Tags: react-native, internationalization, translation

I use i18n in my react app an I wonder about the proper use across my screens. I currently set up the basics in my App.js like so:

```
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";
import i18n from "i18n-js";
import {de} from "./locales/de";
import {en} from "./locales/en";
import {fr} from "./locales/fr";


i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, de, fr };
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
```

So far so good. On my screens I use i18n like this:

```
import i18n from "i18n-js";
import {de} from "../../../locales/de";
import {en} from "../../../locales/en";
import {fr} from "../../../locales/fr";

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, de, fr };

...

<Text> {i18n.t("Welcome")} </Text>
```

Is this the right way to do it? I am going to have hundreds of screens and a lot of text. So loading everything this way on every screen makes me feel.... uncomfortable...Will it have a  big impact on performance? Would using useContext be better?

Also: How long is too long for a language file? Should I maybe create several en english files for different content?

I am very mich interested in your thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: please remove the i18next tag, this is not i18next related

Comment: I removed it :-)